# Writing JavaScript function that generate prime numbers, why are some numbers excluded from the loop?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this function that generates prime numbers for a given range of numbers, I think it's simple and clear that must give the expected result, though, there are numbers that are excluded from the result:

```js
function numberator(from, to) {
    numbers = [];
    for (x = from; x <= to; x++) {
        numbers.push(x);
    }
    return numbers;
}

function primeNumbers(array) {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j < array[i]; j++) {
            if (array[i] % j == 0) {
                array.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(primeNumbers(numberator(1,100)));
```

The result contains: 27, 35 and 95 (also 1, that I may handle later.)

I tried to figure out why but I couldn't.

Comment: What's the range?

Comment: `j = 2; j < array[i]; j++` that looks funky

Comment: Are you sure prime numbers are the result?

Comment: Walk through your code with a debugger and examine variable values as you go along.

Comment: @torazaburo the browser debugger?

Comment: *the browser debugger?* Right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug is in-place modification of **array** with splice. You keep on incrementing i, while the size of array is getting modified at execution time.

You can debug this, by printing the whole array after each slice operation.

Also the solution is highly inefficient and will perform terribly for slightly long ranges. Use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/)

Answer (score 1):

In this

```
array.splice(i, 1);
```

statement you are changing the length of the array but not modifying the index `i` accordingly. Change it to

`array.splice(i--, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share a simple and very easy to understand Javascript code to generate small prime numbers: https://github.com/HMaxF/generate-small-prime-number

Answer (score -1):

Take it more simple :

```
const isPrime = (n =>
        n>1 && 
        Array.from({length: Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n))-1},(e,i) => i+2)
             .every(m => n%m)
);

const generateRange = (from, to) => Array.from({length: to-from + 1}, (v, k) => k+from);
```

then

```
generateRange(1, 100).filter(isPrime); // DONE!
```

```js
//---- Utilities 
const isPrime = (n =>
        n>1 && 
        Array.from({length: Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n))-1},(e,i) => i+2)
             .every(m => n%m)
);

 const generateRange = (from, to) => Array.from({length: to-from + 1}, (v, k) => k+from);

//---------Apply ---
const from = 1;
const to = 100; 

 console.log (
    `Prime numbers from ${from} to ${to} are : `,
    generateRange(from, to).filter(isPrime)
  )
```